# Laravel, add javascript in template to scripts.js file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am finding that if I have specific javascript for a template, I need to actually render it with my overall scripts.js file, not just as a snippet on that particular template. Is there any way to do this in laravel by default?

So append all javascript in the template to the scripts.js file that is compiled? It would just make the output a lot more attractive and would ensure that I have the necessary dependencies and objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Laravel Mix, you can combine multiple scripts together using [mix.scripts()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#vanilla-js).

```
mix.scripts([
    'public/js/admin.js',
    'public/js/dashboard.js'
], 'public/js/all.js');
```

Worth noting, Blade offers the [@push and @stack](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#stacks) directives. This allows you to control when, where and in what order your scripts are output.

Comment: Thanks didge #thumbsup